# How can I control the speed while playing, to match the recording speed in Katalon for Android?

Tags: android, automated-tests, katalon-studio

I am using the Record and play functionality for Android in Katalon Studio. I want the system to replay with the same speed with which the steps were recorded. Please let me know how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set it, you can set just predefined values.
To adjust speed of execution: https://prnt.sc/j5w6dr

Comment: This is applicable to katalon recorder. Katalon studio on the other hand does not have any such setting. I did not get any solution for the android platform in katalon studio